# Adonis: ReferenceError view is not defined

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have controller like this

```
class TicketController {
   index(){
       return view.render('tickets')
    }
}
```

and create file in `resource\view\tickets.edge` and my route is

```
const Route = use('Route')
Route.resource('tickets', 'TicketController');
```

when I go to http://127.0.0.1:3333/tickets show me this error

> ReferenceError
> view is not defined

Comment: That's because... `view` is not defined... I think you forgot to import something.

Comment: What is your question? What is unclear about the error message?

Comment: @user4642212 how can I fix it

Comment: @D.Pardal what's is it exactly?

Comment: I’ve rolled back the edit. The fact that you’re a beginner is irrelevant to the question. _“How can I fix it?”_ — by defining `view`. Read whatever documentation is available to you.

Comment: I followed the documentation https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/views but in documentation dose not say about import 'view'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `view` object from [`http context`](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request-lifecycle#_http_context) :

```js
index ({ view }) {
  return view.render('hello-world')
}
```

[Adonis documentation example](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/views#_basic_example)

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to import `view` class and fix it by this code:

```
const view = use('View');
class TicketController {
   index(){
       return view.render('tickets')
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `view` object from context `index({ view })` : https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/views#_basic_example